# When 'del' key hit on merged cell value Worksheet_Change not triggered

Tags: excel, vba

Cell E12 is merged with cell F12.

If I clear the contents of cell E12 by hitting the "delete" key, cell c39 doesn't change.

If I clear the contents of the cell E12 by using backspace+enter, cell c39 does update.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$12" Then
        Range("d28").Value = Range("e12").Value

        If Range("e12") = "" Then ' update cell c39 with calculator
            Range("c39") = "Do you ?"
        Else
            Range("c39") = "Do you " & Range("e13").Text & "?"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me. Do you have more than one cell highlighted when you hit the `Delete` key?

Comment: yes the cell is merged with cell f12

Comment: update you question please with "the cell is merged with cell f12"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if E12 is included in the selection when `Delete` is pressed. This is necessary because when you hit the `Delete` key, Target.Address is evaluated as `Range("E12:F12")`, but when you enter a value in `E12` Target.Address is just `Range("E12)`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Reset_EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$E$12")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("d28").Value = Range("e12").Value
    If Range("e12") = "" Then    ' update cell c39 with calculator
        Range("c39") = "Do you ?"
    Else
        Range("c39") = "Do you " & Range("e13").Text & "?"
    End If
End If
Reset_EnableEvents:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This will also be triggered if all of column E is selected, cells A1 and E12, etc. That's what the `Intersect` operation does, and I'm guessing that's what you want.

Note that I also added code to turn `EnableEvents` off and on, before and after the heart of your code runs. This keeps your code from triggering additional `Worksheet_Change` events.

Comment: thank you! i just googled and used the if not intersect and it worked as you suggested, what are the other lines of code for? the on error ...

Comment: I was adding to my answer as you were commenting. Let me know if that doesn't explain it. If you google `Worksheet_Change Application.Enableevents` you'll get more lengthy explanations.

Comment: so can i continue adding more if not intersect statements between the enableevents codes?

Comment: @maxgohan The `On Error Goto Reset_EnableEvents` just shifts process flow to the clean-up section of the sub in the event of an error. It's almost definitely not exactly necessary in this circumstance, but it is good code practice and assure that the sub doesn't do something entirely unexpected if something very odd occurs (like an error).

Comment: i see, so it will skip to the end of the code if there is an error instead of resuming after the error, i get it now

Comment: **"so can i continue adding more if not intersect statements"**. Yes, you can connect multiple ones with `ORs`.