# application.onkey = "{DELETE}" VBA excel 2013 to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to connect the DELETE key from the keyboard to a VBA code I have, the reason of doing this is that I have many validations in that sheet so when the user select a range from Sheet4 then he press the delete button it will take long time while executing. How to do it? I have this code to be linked to the DELETE key:

```
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

Worksheets("Sheet4").Range------,clearcontents .how to know the selected range ?
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range------.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

```
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
```

Please help, thanks for any solutions, I am stuck here.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074285/cell-value-not-updated-when-del-key-hit-in-excel